# GPU tensorflow install issue

Tags: tensorflow

I am a new user to Ubuntu, and I spent more than a week trying to install gpu tensorflow. I tried to follow the tutorials from the website and blogs. But whenever I import tensorflow in my python console. It always shows:

```
import tensorflow
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5.1.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:119] Couldn't open CUDA   library libcuda.so.1. LD_LIBRARY_PATH:   :/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:165] hostname: HanGuo
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:189] libcuda reported version is: Not found: was unable to find libcuda.so DSO loaded into this program
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:193] kernel reported version is: Permission denied: could not open driver version path for reading: /proc/driver/nvidia/version
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1091]  LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1092] failed to find libcuda.so on this system: Failed precondition: could not dlopen DSO: libcuda.so.1; dlerror: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.367.57: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
```

I tried to search the answer all over google, but no real solution came up yet.Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Give us more information on how did you install Tensorflow and Cuda.

Comment: I download the CUDA .run file from Nvidia website, and install cuda into: `/usr/local/cuda` using `$ sudo tar -xzvf cudnn-8.0-linux-x64-v5.1.tgz`
`$ sudo cp cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include`
`$ sudo cp cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64`
`$ sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h` `/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*`. The tensorflow was downloaded using `git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow` , and the `./configure`

Comment: basically I followed exactly as (https://alliseesolutions.wordpress.com/2016/09/08/install-gpu-tensorflow-from-sources-w-ubuntu-16-04-and-cuda-8-0-rc/) said.

Comment: Did you run $ sudo sh cuda_8.0.44_linux.run --override? Whats the output of $ ls /usr/local/cuda?

Comment: `bin  extras   jre    libnsight  nvml  pkgconfig  share  tools
doc  include  lib64  libnvvp    nvvm  samples    src    version.txt
`

Answer (score 2):

Based on the output for `$ ls /usr/local/cuda`, you have installed it successfully.

Now, what is missing there is the PATH definition so that TensorFlow can find where it is.

1) Open your .bashrc file: `gedit ~/.bashrc`

2) Append the following two lines to the end of the file:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/include"  
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
```

3) Once you save and close the text file you can return to your original terminal and type this command to reload your .bashrc file:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Although the third part is supposed to take care of that, if you want to be 100% sure that it will work restart the computer.

Now, for TensorFlow, remember to set the CUDA path as `/usr/local/cuda` and the version to 8.0.

Answer (score -1):

install libcuda5-dev might solve your problem