# Why do I get an ImportError when I import TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to install tensorflow and now I'm stuck with the following warning:

```
ranj@ranj-Aspire-V3-772G:~$ python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'  # for Python 3Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.375.39: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  ...
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.375.39: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Can someone tell me how I can solve it?

Comment: Have you installed the GPU version? Did you install the required CUDA dependencies?

Comment: @kaufmanu yes I installed the GPU version but said no to installing graphic drivers. I did so because the installation kept failing.

Comment: Could you add some more information to your post how you installed tensorflow exactly and which version (e.g. if you used a nightly build, if you built it on your own from source or if you used pip etc.)? Also, did you install cuDNN and CUDA toolkit?

Comment: @kaufmanu I also used ctrl+alt+f1 and it keeps asking for a password and when I provide it with the password of my pc login to ubuntu, it gives me an incorrect feedback

Comment: I followed the instructions on https://alliseesolutions.wordpress.com/2016/09/08/install-gpu-tensorflow-from-sources-w-ubuntu-16-04-and-cuda-8-0-rc/

Comment: except for installing the drivers

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly caused the error you report, but it seems like an issue with CUDA and/or communication with the NVIDIA card in general. Also, I don't know why the installation of the graphics driver failed as you mention in the comments, but if you want to have GPU support, having a working graphics driver is essential obviously. So either the driver you have currently installed works fine already or then you will have to find out why installing a new version of the driver fails.

You could proceed like this:

- Make sure your graphics card fulfills the requirements (CUDA compute capability >= 3.0, check the compute capability of your card [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)).
- Make sure your installation of cuDNN and CUDA Toolkit works fine. For this, you could follow the instructions [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/#verify-installation) (point 6.2.2).
- If this works fine, it might just be that Tensorflow cannot find the required CUDA libraries. Check this related Stackoverflow post: [GPU tensorflow install issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40440542/gpu-tensorflow-install-issue)

As a side note: the tutorial you linked in the comments seems to suggest that you have to build Tensorflow from source using bazel, which is in fact not always necessary. I would recommend you take a look at the [official installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux) - those are pretty comprehensive and consider all the details you require for the installation. So if all fails, consider starting from scratch and follow the official tutorial linked above.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it in gnome (ctrl+alt+f3) and logged in with my account and then used:
"sudo init 3"
"sudo -i"
Went to downloads dir and installed the nvidia driver: "sh NVIDIAxxx.run"
"reboot"

In the gnome I can use python3 and import tensorflow

The problem is now that I cannot login to the os in the normal manner. I still can log into the gmome